# How to replace values of an array using numpy array and numpy.where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some data as:

```
data1={'v': [(0, 103), (1, 4), (2, 50), (3, 101), (4, 156), (5, 110)]}
data2=[[2, 1, 1.0], [2, 0, 1.0], [3, 0, 1.0], [3, 2, 1.0], [4, 2, 1.0], [4, 0, 1.0], [5, 3, 1.0], [5, 0, 1.0], [1, 3, 1.0], [1, 0, 1.0]]
```

Now, I want to replace every first tuple value with the second tuple value of data1 in data2. For example I want to replace 0 with 103 where ever it occurs in data2, which can be done using the code below, but I want to track whether if there has been one replacement so that another doesn't happen at that position again like 1 gets replaced by 4 (second tuple) but then 4 itself gets replaced by 196, which in turn leads to a replacement as 1-->196. which I don't want. So can anyone help me in preventing this?

```
data2=numpy.array([[2, 1, 1.0], [2, 0, 1.0], [3, 0, 1.0], [3, 2, 1.0], [4, 2, 1.0], [4, 0, 1.0], [5, 3, 1.0], [5, 0, 1.0], [1, 3, 1.0], [1, 0, 1.0]])

for i in range(len(data1.values()[0])):
    data2=numpy.where(data2==data1.values()[0][i][0],data1.values()[0][i][1],data2)
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy? You have a python list and a dict. Can you add your expected output also?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job more suited to using another dict and a list comp where the dict is the mapping of each element to replace and with what:

```
data1 = {'v': [(0, 103), (1, 4), (2, 50), (3, 101), (4, 156), (5, 110)]}
data2 = [[2, 1, 1.0], [2, 0, 1.0], [3, 0, 1.0], [3, 2, 1.0], [4, 2, 1.0], [4, 0, 1.0], [5, 3, 1.0], [5, 0, 1.0],
         [1, 3, 1.0], [1, 0, 1.0]]
repl = dict(*data1.values())

data2[:] = [[repl.get(ele, ele) for ele in sub] for sub in data2]

print(data2)
```

If the ele is in the dict it gets replaced by the value, if not just keep the original element. This is going to be a lot faster than your own numpy approach. Why your logic fails is you are repeatedly reassigning data2 in your loop so you  end up replacing values you already replaced. You would need to do the assignment once but again this is really simple to accomplish using pure python with a dict mapping.